# Is there an API to make image your wallpaper in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Is there any way to set an image as your background wallpaper directly from an iOS app?

Answer (score 1):

### No.

There is no public API for doing this - your best bet is going to be saving the image to the user's camera role and presenting instructions on how to set the wallpaper.